# Flask 301 redirect on some parameters

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

I am setting up a simple **flask REST API** but ran into an issue when testing where only one of my `id`'s is causing the application to throw a `301`. I can't tell why this `ID` is behaving differently then all the others.

```
object_view = ObjectView.as_view('object') #subclass of MethodView
app.add_url_rule('/objects/',  view_func=object_view, methods=['GET',])
app.add_url_rule('/objects/', view_func=object_view, methods=['POST',])
app.add_url_rule('/objects/<object_id>', view_func=object_view, methods=['GET',])
```

This routing code works great except when `object_id` is `88d63017-25ac-4c81-a637-1e6207986bc4`. When I use that object_id I get a `301` and redirect to the base `/objects/` list.

I tried it with trailing slashes as well and that does seem to fix it `/objects/88d63017-25ac-4c81-a637-1e6207986bc4/` returns a `200` as expected but I am unsure of why this works and it breaks my conventions to do so.

Comment: I think that the implementation of `ObjectView.get()` might have some bearing on this issue. Could you add the code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that using Advanced Rest Client had cached that local response somewhere along the way. Using curl I was able to get a valid response.

Thanks for the help all